# GWT Ajax call without using RPC

Tags: ajax, gwt, rpc

I have a client side class that takes a long time to be constructed, specifically,
com.bradrydzewski.gwt.calendar.client.Calendar;

Is there a way I can pass off the construction of this class to an ajax call so it doesn't block?

```
Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
```

I can't use RPC because this Calendar is not serializable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be helpful if you could give any insight into why it's taking a long time.

If the "long time" is taken by DOM manipulation that has to happen on the client, asynchronicity won't help you. JavaScript is single-threaded, so any cpu-bound task is going to drag the whole page down while it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I would use separate **Transfer Object** class to store the details of your Calendar and then pass it to server side (RPC or plain Ajax, doesn't matter).